# responisive div width combined with fixed width div pure CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, width, percentage

I have a webpage that is vertically divided in two parts:

- Div1: One with a fixed width (200px), containing a menu
- Div2: One with a percentual width, containing images

Is there a pure CSS way of scaling the Div2 so that it will always fill the "space" that is left when scaling?

Here an image to illustrate the idea (ignore the margin between the divs). Notice that the left div keeps his `200px` width, and the other div gets the width of the remaining.

[image]

I was thinking of something like:

```
#div2{
    width: 100% - 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the overall design (*if using floats you can do it with margins*)

But for modern browsers there is also the `calc()` function.

```
#div2{
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```